# SQLAlchemy Session Errormessages

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I want to wrap my database-operations into sessions (transactions). For a good user experience I want to try to handle as many possible errors inside my code. My basic structure of a database transaction is in the code block.

There are two kinds of error:

1. My code can try to handle them, for ex. a user try to insert a key that already exists.
2. Some other exception raise, that was not handled by the code.

In both situations, I want to show the user a message.

How can I give out the error, so that I can display it after the session was closed?

```
# Transaction
session = Session()
try:
  db_operation1(session, ...)
  db_operation2(session, ...)
  ...
  session.commit()
except:
  session.rollback()
finally:
  session.close()

# Show error
# ???
```

Edit:

After some investigation, I change my code to this:

```
# Transaction
session = Session()
try:
  db_operation1(session, ...)
  db_operation2(session, ...)
  ...
  session.commit()
except Exception as e:
  session.rollback()
  # Show Error
  print(str(e))
finally:
  session.close()
```

But in the case, my code can handle the exception, I need some more user friendly message.

Edit2:

As snakecharmerb points me to, it is better to handle the exception outside the session-scope, I change the code again:

```
try:
  # Transaction
  session = Session()
  try:
    db_operation1(session, ...)
    db_operation2(session, ...)
    ...
    session.commit()
  except:
    session.rollback()
    raise
  finally:
    session.close()
except Exception as e:
  # Show Error
  print(str(e))
```

Comment: Relevant: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it

Comment: Hello snakecharmerb, the document you point to, is what I used in the past. What is wrong with my example code?

Comment: The code isn't _wrong_, but (1) it mixes session management and db operations, which they doc advises against  (2) As shown in the context manager example, the error gets re-raised in the `except` block so that the application can handle it

Comment: (1) I don't agree. It is done like the document tells me under the line "Keep the lifecycle of the session (and usually the transaction) separate and external:" and for (2) I do not exactly understand where my error get raised again.

Comment: ok, I understand (2) now.

Comment: ok, (1) I think it is a missunderstanding. db_operation1 and db_operation2 are not tow things in my example, they are parts of one and the same transaction.